# Why does biblatex-chicago sort articles without an author by journaltitle rather than title?

Tags: sorting, biblatex-chicago

According to the documentation for `biblatex-chicago (notes)`, articles with no `author` field should be sorted alphabetically by `title` in the bibliography, except when the journaltitle's subtype is `magazine`. However, biblatex-chicago seems to be sorting all anonymous articles by `journaltitle` instead, even when there is no subtype. Is this a bug? If so, how can one work around it?

Example -- note the sorting order:

[image]

```
\RequirePackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{1885,
    journaltitle = {Johns Hopkins University Circulars},
    pages = {15-21},
    title = {Preliminary Register of Officers and Students},
    volume = {5},
    year = {1885}}    
@article{1892d,
    journaltitle = {Nation},
    pages = {238},
    title = {Books of the Week},
    volume = {54},
    year = {1892}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago} % load 'notes & bibliography' style
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Answer (score 2):

The sorting template is defined in `chicago-notex.cbx` is

```latex
\DeclareSortingTemplate{cms}{% Updated for biblatex > 3.7
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{namea}
    \field{editor}
    \field{nameb}
    \field{translator}
    \field{namec}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{journaltitle}
    \field{organization}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}
```

and you should clearly see the issue.

Redefine it to your needs. I exchanged `title` and `journaltitle`.

```latex
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname.bib}
@article{1885,
    journaltitle = {Johns Hopkins University Circulars},
    pages = {15-21},
    title = {Preliminary Register of Officers and Students},
    volume = {5},
    year = {1885}}    
@article{1890,
    journaltitle = {Xohns Hopkins University Circulars},
    pages = {15-21},
    title = {Preliminary Register of Officers and Students},
    volume = {5},
    year = {1890}}    
@article{1892d,
    journaltitle = {Nation},
    pages = {238},
    title = {Books of the Week},
    volume = {54},
    year = {1892}}
\end{filecontents}

\documentclass{article}    
\usepackage[notes]{biblatex-chicago} % load 'notes & bibliography' style
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}

\DeclareSortingTemplate{cms}{% Updated for biblatex > 3.7
  \sort{
    \field{presort}
  }
  \sort[final]{
    \field{sortkey}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortname}
    \field{author}
    \field{namea}
    \field{editor}
    \field{nameb}
    \field{translator}
    \field{namec}
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
    \field{organization}
    \field{journaltitle}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sorttitle}
    \field{title}
  }
  \sort{
    \field{sortyear}
    \field{year}
  }
  \sort{
    \field[padside=left,padwidth=4,padchar=0]{volume}
    \literal{0000}
  }
}

\begin{document}
\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: That worked, thanks @egreg! Is it the norm to contact the package author in such cases, since it was supposed to sort by title?

Comment: @Trevor I guess so.